# Backup solution advice for  a small development team

Tags: linux, rsync, tape, backup

I'm a developer who works from home and I get alot of graphics, apps and code that I need to  backup. Thhe critical data is about 10GB and all the rest is about 100GB. Should I buy a tape device? Or maybe blue-ray burner? Remote backup? Buy a machine and install rsync and Ubuntu?

Comment: Please go through some of your old questions and mark accepted answers. This will encourage people to continue trying to help you in the future. Also, please take the time to use proper Capitalization and punctuation when you write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't know anything about

- How much your data change daily
- How fast is your internet connection
- How big is your budget for this

we can't really help you.

I only recommend to think about offsite backup if this is technically feasible (internet speed). A tape drive on your desk or the backup machine in the basement won't help you if your house is on fire. Everything else is up to you.

(BTW: Please go through your older questions and accept answers if appropriate)

Comment: i got internet connection is cable : 1900kb/s down and 300 kb up,
data changes daily i estimate about 500mb - 2gb
budget? under from 100-1000$ 
i tried backup services but they are not relaible sometimes its stack at the upload and in the long term you see after a month that 50% of your data are partly backuped or files are missing

is tape device are considered "old fashioned" like 1.44 diskettes for backup?

hope now you can give me better answer

Answer (score 0):

I always use [jwz's Backup PSA](http://www.jwz.org/doc/backups.html) as a starting point for these conversations. It's mostly disaster recovery, and doesn't consider version control or incrementals. But honestly, if you do versioning right, then the version control repository is just more data that you need to keep backed up.